# Protractor tests always fails in Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, protractor

I have just started to write protractor tests... It runs perfectly fine with Chrome. However, It is failing with FF. While looking at some of the related posts in StackOverFlow, I added these steps.. But still failing.

1.Starting the selenium server on my local and explicitly defining the FF path
2.Setting the browser size

Not sure why it is failing .. Help is much appreciated.

1.java -jar selenium-server.jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
2.browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

Error:

```
    C:\MyWebPage 2.0>protractor Conf.js
[launcher] Running 2 instances of WebDriver
.F.F..
------------------------------------
[firefox #2] PID: 7436
[firefox #2] Specs: C:\MyWebPage 2.0\tests\WebPage.js
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2] Using the selenium server at http://:4444/wd/hub
[firefox #2] .FF.

------------------------------------

[firefox #2]
[firefox #2] Failures:
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2]   1) angularjs homepage should the title contain
[firefox #2]    Message:
[firefox #2]      Expected 'Username / Password Sign In' to equal 'MyWebPage'.

[firefox #2]    Stacktrace:
[firefox #2]      Error: Failed expectation
[firefox #2]     at null.<anonymous> (C:\MyWebPage 2.0\tests\WebPage.js:21:3
2)
[firefox #2]     at C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:94:14
[firefox #2]     at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\sra
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdri
ver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1640:20)
[firefox #2]     at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runEventLoop_ (C:\Users\sra
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriv
er\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1505:8)
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2]   2) angularjs homepage Should click on the sub menu
[firefox #2]    Message:
[firefox #2]      NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.linkTex
t("PowerGuide")
[firefox #2]    Stacktrace:
[firefox #2]      NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.linkTex
t("PowerGuide")
[firefox #2]     at new bot.Error (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:113:18)
[firefox #2]     at C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\lib\protractor.js:692:17
[firefox #2]     at C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
[firefox #2]     at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\sra
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdri
ver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1640:20)
[firefox #2]     at notify (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modul
es\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:444:12)
[firefox #2]     at notifyAll (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:422:7)

[firefox #2]     at resolve (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:400:7)
[firefox #2]     at fulfill (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:512:5)
[firefox #2]     at C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protr
actor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:1582:15
[firefox #2]     at webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (C:\Users\sra
\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdri
ver\lib\webdriver\promise.js:1640:20)
[firefox #2] ==== async task ====
[firefox #2] Asynchronous test function: it()
[firefox #2]     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd\index.js:93:33)
[firefox #2]     at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\async-callback.js:45:37
)
[firefox #2]     at jasmine.Block.execute (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:1
174:17)
[firefox #2]     at jasmine.Queue.next_ (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:220
9:31)
[firefox #2]     at null._onTimeout (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:2199:18
)
[firefox #2] Error
[firefox #2]     at null.<anonymous> (C:\MyWebPage 2.0\tests\WebPage.js:25:3
)
[firefox #2]     at jasmine.Env.describe_ (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming
\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:9
13:21)
[firefox #2]     at jasmine.Env.describe (C:\Users\sran\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:89
8:15)
[firefox #2]     at describe (C:\Users\srrr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\protractor\node_modules\minijasminenode\lib\jasmine-1.3.1.js:658:27)
[firefox #2]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MyWebPage 2.0\tests\WebPage.js:2:
1)
[firefox #2]
[firefox #2] Finished in 11.628 seconds
[firefox #2] 4 tests, 2 assertions, 2 failures
[firefox #2]

[launcher] Runner Process Exited With Error Code: 1
[launcher] 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
..
------------------------------------
[chrome #1] PID: 8128
[chrome #1] Specs: C:\MyWebPage 2.0\tests\WebPage.js
[chrome #1]
[chrome #1] Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[chrome #1] ....

------------------------------------

[chrome #1]
[chrome #1] Finished in 13.642 seconds
[chrome #1] 4 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures
[chrome #1]

[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #1 passed
[launcher] firefox #2 failed 2 test(s)
[launcher] overall: 2 failed spec(s)

C:\MyWebPage 2.0>
```

Comment: Seems like no one has any clue on this. It passes sometime.Out of 5 failures, 2 times it passes. Why it fails the other 3 times, I don't know.

Comment: Where are your tests? All we can see now is a huge stack strace...

Comment: what is your firefox version